# Enums in Random function

Tags: c

I have an enum with a specific set of values. I need a function to throw random output from the enum set of values every time the  function is called. Can someone help? The function should be in C.

```
typedef enum fruits
{
 Apple     = 0x00,
 Orange    = 0x04,
 Mango     = 0x07,
 Pineapple = 0x08
}Fruits_T;

Fruits_T random_function()
{
  return (rand(Fruits_T));
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Consider using xmacros

Comment: `enum fruits random_function(void) { int tmp = rand() % 4; return (tmp*(25-tmp*tmp))/6; }`

Comment: @pmg let rand()%4 gives 1st value as 2. then, temp =2; return(2*(25-2*2))/6 gives us 2. Whats the use of the return function as it gives the same output as rand()%4.

Comment: @sahoo845: the calculation is `(2*(25-2*2))/6` == `(2*(25-4))/6` == `(2*(21))/6` == `(42)/6` == `7`

Comment: @sahoo845 see https://ideone.com/oWT9hp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Call `srand` once somewhere in the beginning of your program.
- Store all possible values of the enum in an array with size `n`.
- Call `rand(n)` and use the result as array index, to return the value stored there.

Comment: srand is used for setting the seed. Anyways rand() function is already set with a seed value of 1. So is there any specific reason of calling srand() in the beginning?

Comment: @sahoo845 you call srand (read it's documentation), so you won't get the same sequence of pseudo random numbers on each run of your program.

Comment: Also can you help me how can I call the array from the rand() so that i get random values?

Comment: @sahoo845 Call `rand(n)` where `n` is the array size. Store the result in an integer as use that as index for accessing the array.

Comment: @Lundin thanks for the update. But isn't there a way in which values from enum can be directly used without using an array?

Comment: @sahoo845 Not unless you can cook up some mathematic formula for it. I don't see an obvious pattern in the choice of numbers. If the enum had used adjacent numbers it would have been another story. An array is a generic solution independent of the enum values.